# Python Tkinter Entry. I can't type Korean in to the Entry field

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a p2p chat program in Python 3 using Tkinter. I can paste Korean text into the Entry widget and send to the other user and it works.

However, I can't 'type' Korean into the widget directly.

Why is this happening?

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: tkinter 8.5 had this problem, update it to 8.6

Comment: ActiveState tcl/tk 8.5.18 should work.  See https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/.  8.6 will not work with the PSF distributed python.

Comment: @whiteSkar is this resolved?

Comment: @Hippolippo I haven't tried updating my tkinter to 8.6 so my problem hasn't been resolved (decided not to support Korean) but I would assume the first comment is the solution I would accept if it was not a 'comment' but an 'answer'.

Comment: @Hippolippo Just upgraded my python version to 3.8 to have tkinter 8.6. Confirmed that the problem is resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @mohit-bhasi, upgrading my python version to 3.8 which has tkinter 8.6 in it solved the problem. I can now type Korean directly into the widgets.

Only caveat is that I need to press right arrow once when I finished typing to have the last letter appear. Otherwise, the last letter is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `translate` module by `pip install translate` into your python shell. It uses google translate offline as a python module.
It would work something like this:
 `$ translate-kor -t zh "This is a pen."`

More details on `translate` can be found at the link https://pypi.org/project/translate/.

Once you have this, you can probably integrate it into your chat program, as you could easily save the translation to a variable. This is a viable alternative if you are not able to update your tkinter python module.